# How can I resolve "sbcl.fasl" not found when trying to install usocket library for common-lisp [sbcl / WSL1 - Ubuntu 18.04.5]

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, quicklisp, usocket

I'm trying to use dexador library for lisp and cannot install it. I'm using quicklisp as package manager. I've been trying to use the command

```
(ql:quicklisp :dexador)
```

to load the desired library.

this command fails with given message :

```
COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while
compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "usocket" "backend" "sbcl">
    [Condition of type UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR]
```

after a bit of research, it appears that it's actually usocket that prevents from compiling.
If if put a breakpoint on errors in the lisp environment using :

```
(setf *break-on-signals* 'error)
```

When i try to load usocket, using :

```
(ql:quickload :usocket)
```

I get the following error :

```
Failed to find _Personal_/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.4.5.debian-linux-x64/_Personal_/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/usocket-0.8.4/backend/sbcl.fasl:
  No such file or directory
BREAK was entered because of *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* (now rebound to NIL)
```

could someone help me finding why isn't this file compiled and how to compile it in the right place so that I can import the desired lib.

another info is that I get the same behaviour when trying to import Drakma lib - depends on usocket also.

Comment: Is it a fresh install or did you use another version of SBCL before? Are you effectively running SBCL 1.4.5?

Comment: I just had a compile error today with usocket and the latest Quicklisp (dist version `2022-04-01`, no releases since yet). It was due to a missing `sb-int:broken-pipe` symbol, which is fixed upstream. What is your QL version? `(ql:dist-version "quicklisp")`